# Date Picker Selector for Input Field

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the color of the date picker that shows in some browsers but don't know the selector's name.

HTML:

```
<form action="pledge.html" method="post">       
    <input type="date" id="birthday" name="user_bday">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

input {
    height: 45px;
    width: 40%;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 90px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}

input[type="date"] {
  /*Something Goes Here Probably*/
}
```

Here's a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/froggomad/gznx60j1/25/

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want to change the color of the tabular datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 8 pseudo elements that are available for customization by default using webkit

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field
::-webkit-inner-spin-button
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
```

and sadly, there is no cross browser way of styling a native date picker.

Answer (score 0):

your selector is okay.

```
input[type="date"] {
   /*CSS Rules*/
}
```

If your codes run on one browser and don't run on another browser, then you need to write **Cross Browser Supported** Codes with the prefix such as **`-webkit- , -moz-`** etc.

But, I will suggest you to use https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ for flexibility and more features.

Comment: the selector for the input field is fine, yes. But idk the name of the date picker. Thanks for the tip about the jquery date picker